# What do I need to do to enable version control?

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning

I have full control on SharePoint site and have enabled Version Control on my list, however I do not see any versions when I click on the ellipsis next to my list in Site Contents.  What else do I need to do to enable version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did already enabled version control. To view the version history

- Select the list item and
- Click on the File tab on the top ribbon and you can see the version history option.
- Click on it to view the versions on that item.

Comment: Version control is for list items I believe. Not for the whole list itself

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, to view the version history:[image]

Reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/5-ways-users-can-benefit-versioning-sharepoint/